# AGPL license - RStudio Server

Tags: gpl, agpl-3.0, gnu

I know that there are certainly already many questions on this topic - I have also read through quite a few, but unfortunately still do not understand it.

I am in the process of deploying an RShiny app on the web. The goal is to use the app commercially.

I would like to run the app over my own infrastructure and ShinyProxy, Docker etc - at a later date.

For now, I would go the easier route via AWS and RShiny Server. However, RShiny Server is AGPL licensed. What does that mean for me?

I understand that I can use RShiny Server commercially without any problems - as long as I don't change anything in the source code - even without having to make the rest of my source code available, right?

The whole licensing issue is difficult to understand for a layman - I hope you have a tip for me!

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with the mechanisms of Shiny Server and Shiny Apps. Have you looked at [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/interpretation-of-agpl-with-shiny-server)?  I also find [this page in the RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/legal-department-of-public-institution-concerned-about-shiny-server-agpl/40731) helpful.